# How to serialize little-endian PODs painlessly?

Tags: haskell, serialization

Let's say I have the following type:

```
data WaveFormatChunk = WaveFormatChunk { 
    compression :: Word16,
    channels :: Word16,
    sampleRate :: Word32,
    averageBps :: Word32,
    blockAlign :: Word16,
    significantBits :: Word16
    } deriving (Show)
```

Is there a way to just dump all of that into a ByteString (or a similar structure) wholesale (in a manner of ye olde C structs)? If not and I have to write a function that separately puts all of them to a list, are there at least functions to make sticking the value into a, say, Word8 list easy? Something like putWordBBxe, except for byte strings or list (though I'm most likely severely mistaken since I haven't properly read into Monads yet, it seems to me that Get/Put are mostly used with streams).

Data.Binary isn't quite what I'm looking for, it seems more useful for just dumping data on disc than storing it in a specific format with a specific (and "wrong") endianness.

Comment: Writing a [`Storable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Storable.html) instance for `WaveFormatChunk` is pretty straightforward. That'll let you write (`poke`) and read (`peek`) `WaveFormatChunk`s to and from memory locations (as if they were ye olde C structs). These can then be turned into `ByteString`s if you so wish. I don't know if this is quite what you're looking for, but I can elaborate if you wish. There's also the [binary package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) for serialization.

Comment: ... oh, I see my edit about the binary package was pretty worthless since you already knew about that :-)

Comment: Storable is definitely the way to go.  You won't get closer to C than that, both in implementation style and efficiency.  [Here is an example](http://hpaste.org/76299).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that @GabrielGonzalez' nice example uses [hsc2hs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html), a tool that assists with the repetitive boring task of writing `Storable` instances for C structs. For example hsc2hs turns `#{peek point, x}` into a suitable [`peek :: Ptr a -> IO a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Storable.html#v:peek) for accessing the `x` field of the C type `point`.

Comment: The binary package is perfectly fine for byte-level control. It also has IO primitives, but it was originally designed for wire-level protocols

Comment: I should probably clear something up - by C struct-esque I meant specifically the ability to just dump the entire struct to a file rather than explicitly writing each field. `Storable` looks very nice, though it seems more geared towards FFI (is this a problem?), which I don't need, and the lack of pure functions scares me a tiny bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Data.Binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.4.1) will let you serialize the structure to a bytestring, using explicitly [little-endian operators](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.4.1/doc/html/Data-Binary-Put.html#5).

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -funbox-strict-fields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

import Data.Binary
import Data.Binary.Put

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy  as L

data WaveFormatChunk =
        WaveFormatChunk { 
            compression     :: !Word16,
            channels        :: !Word16,
            sampleRate      :: !Word32,
            averageBps      :: !Word32,
            blockAlign      :: !Word16,
            significantBits :: !Word16
        } 

instance Binary WaveFormatChunk where
    put (WaveFormatChunk{..}) = do
        putWord16le compression 
        putWord16le channels
        putWord32le sampleRate
        putWord32le averageBps
        putWord16le blockAlign
        putWord16le significantBits

    get = undefined

main = C.putStr $ C.concat $ L.toChunks $ encode test
  where
    test = WaveFormatChunk {
            compression     = 0xcafe
          , channels        = 0xface
          , sampleRate      = 0xdeadbeef
          , averageBps      = 0xf01dab1e
          , blockAlign      = 0x5566
          , significantBits = 0xb01d
          }
```

Will yield:

```
 $ ./A | od -x
 0000000 cafe face beef dead ab1e f01d 5566 b01d
```

So you have precise byte-level control of the representation. You can also get  the same effect from the cereal package, if you're not interested in streaming.

Comment: Thanks - a probably noobish question, but I'm only vaguely familiar with strictness declarations and all the jazz that goes with them... are the bangs there actually necessary?

Comment: They're good hygiene -- you don't need laziness here, laziness on atomic types is almost always wrong -- so specify that it should be strict.

Comment: Note that the binary package now supports streaming too, you don't need to pick between binary and cereal anymore.

Answer (score 4):

There is another, completely different approach.  Instead of having such a structure you can define a `ByteString` wrapper:

```
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

newtype WaveFormatChunk =
    WaveFormatChunk {
      getWaveFormatChunk :: ByteString
    }
```

Writing this to a file is straightforward.  To modify such a structure you can use lenses:

```
data Compression = {- ... -}

compression :: Lens' WaveFormatChunk Compression
```

or if you prefer:

```
compression :: Lens' WaveFormatChunk Word16
```

The lenses act like safe interpreters of the individual byte groups.  However, there are three problems:  First of all you should employ a test framework for that one, because it's easy to get the lenses wrong.  Secondly every change requires a new copy of the ByteString.  Depending on what you do this can be slower or faster than your original approach.

My personal recommendation is to go with a regular high level Haskell datatype and use proper serialization.  As pointed out by others the instances are pretty easy to write.